# Set with elements in any open interval

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose a set of real numbers has infimum b and superemum a. Further suppose that if x and y are within the set, then another real number between x and y is also within the set. Must it be true that any open interval that is a subset of (b,a) must contain an element of the set? If so, what is the proof? I apologize if this happens to be a well-known theorem; if it is, please just cite the name of the theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, see for instance the set $[0,1)\cup (2,3]$.

Comment: I was about to say $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$.